# Rails authentication checks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have this `authenticate!` method where I am trying to retrieve their account based on the subdomain, then find the user. if user is found & their password is matched, we return `success`, else `fail` in all other cases. here is the code:

```
def authenticate!
    account = Account.find_by(subdomain: subdomain)
    if account
      u = account.users.find_by email: params["user"]["email"]
      if u.nil?
        fail!
      else
        u.authenticate(params["user"]["password"]) ? success!(u) : fail!
      end
    else
      fail!
    end
end
```

Now, I could simply this further by moving subdomain into a helper method,

```
def subdomain
  ActionDispatch::Http::URL.extract_subdomains(request.host, 1)
end

def authenticate!
      account = Account.find_by(subdomain: subdomain)
      if account
        u = account.users.find_by email: params["user"]["email"]
        if u.nil?
          fail!
        else
          u.authenticate(params["user"]["password"]) ? success!(u) : fail!
        end
      else
        fail!
      end
end
```

But how to I simply these nested conditionals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another view on @tokland solution:

```
def authenticate!
  return fail! unless account = Account.find_by(subdomain: subdomain)
  return fail! unless user = account.users.find_by(email: params["user"]["email"])
  return fail! unless user.authenticate(params["user"]["password"])
  success! user
end
```

This intention is to be as close to "original task explained in common English" as possible. And `return` keyword allows me to do that.

Comment: While this is probably the more idiomatic in Ruby (in the sense that is what most Ruby programmers would write), and saves some lines, personally I dislike (enormously) 1) early returns, 2) inline conditionals, for a piece of code that is an expression. My rationale: https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

Comment: I don't care, what do most Ruby programmers write. My way is to be as close to "original task explained in common English" as possible. And `return` keyword allows me to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Some programmers don't like the pattern `if (var = value)` (for understandable reasons), unfortunately, by avoiding it at all costs, you end up writing verbose code like yours. If you have no problems with it:

```
def authenticate!
  if (account = Account.find_by(subdomain: subdomain)) &&
     (user = account.users.find_by(email: params["user"]["email"])) &&
     user.authenticate(params["user"]["password"])
    success!(user)
  else
    fail!
  end
end
```

Note that the parens are there to make more clear that we are doing an assignment and not a comparison (and to avoid operator precendence problems)

Answer (score 1):

Symantic variant of @Nakilon's answer:

```
  def authenticate!
    user = nil
    return success!(user) if
      account = Account.find_by(subdomain: subdomain)) and
      user = account.users.find_by(email: params["user"]["email"]) and
      user.authenticate(params["user"]["password"])
    return fail!  
  end
```

I prefer @Nakilon, but thought this might be of some interest.  Note: 1) `user` must be initialized (to anything); and 2) the line continuation mark `\` is not needed where it's obvious to Ruby that the statement is not complete.  I don't know if the latter conforms to the Ruby style guide.